# Best authentication/security strategy for WCF service with multiple clients

Tags: c#, wcf, security, authentication, cross-platform

I've been asked to investigate WCF security and authentication in order to build a set of web services that fit into our business application.

Currently our application is written with ASP.NET with a lot of back-end code written in C#, and some WCF services which rely on forms authentication. Unfortunately, as time has progressed, the code base has become very ad-hoc, therefore there is no real logical separation/layering.

In the grand scheme of things, we want a structured application with a data access layer, business logic layer, data transport layer (WCF) and various presentation layers (of which the ASP.NET website will be one).

I've been told that in future, we may also support presentation layers written using Windows Forms, WPF, Console Applications and even some written in Java (for Linux and Mac users).

I'm relatively new to WCF. I understand the basic principles of it, but when it comes to authentication/security, I'm definitely no expert!

I know there are lots of different strategies for authentication/security in WCF; I'm looking for the most suitable given the range of presentation platforms. So, given the scenario of using ASP.NET, Windows Forms, WPF, Java as the various presentation layers, what is the best strategy for authentication and security in WCF services?

Answer (score 1):

The best strategy for you is going to depend on your security requirements.  In other words, there is not a best strategy that applies to all solutions.

I would suggest taking a look at the [WCF Security Guide](http://wcfsecurityguide.codeplex.com/).  It will get you up to speed on the basics of security in WCF.  It also has sections for common Intranet and Internet scenarios with prescriptive guidance for each.  Based on the little bit of information you've provided here, I think you will find one of these scenarios aligns to your needs.  The guide is old, but still very relevant.

Later, you may want to look at the benefits of moving to a claims-based security model.  This is a huge topic so I'll just point you to [this guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff423674.aspx) for future reference.